# Start Native Camera without showing chooser

Tags: android

Is it possible to start native android camera app that starts default camera instead of showing intent chooser and then start activity to get results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the Camera app by using a intent, like in:
[Android camera intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent)

You can set a specific class in your intent like this:
`Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");`
`intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.Camera");`

This will not show the intent-chooser and launch the default Camera-app.

Comment: This doesnot works. It gave error to register this activity in manifest and i did that as well. but still the problem is there

Comment: This will not work across different phones since many OEMs use their own camera with different class/package names.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748605/starting-video-camera-with-intent

Comment: **setClassName** doesn't work, without this line it works but if there are some 3rd party application like **Line Camera**, **Paper Camera** are installed in your phone above action will open a chooser. So how to open default camera without showing chooser?

Comment: Check what the package and class of the camera-app is, and put that information in setClassName.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);            
 startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) { 
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } 

    }
```

In Manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

Comment: This asks for chooser. I want to start native android camera only and i want to hide the chooser means it directly opens native camera application.