# Record intent save to custom dir/file

Tags: android, android-intent

I need something like this, but for a record intent 
**(**Intent recordIntent = new Intent(
MediaRecorder recorder;     **)**          :

```
           Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "SecExPhotos");
           imagesFolder.mkdirs(); // <----
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
           File image = new File(imagesFolder, date + ".jpg");
           Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);
           cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uriSavedImage);
           startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 2);
```

I hope it is posibile.

Comment: It's in the same class.. 2 seconds of searching would find "MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE"

Comment: check out [this solution][1] 

Cheers!

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748605/starting-video-camera-with-intent

Comment: no, sorry I mean a voice record. :-/