# how can turn on camera to video in android

Tags: java, android

how can i do it this is my code

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;
    ImageView mImageView;
    Button btn;



    public void imageCapture(){
            Intent picture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(picture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
            {
                startActivityForResult(picture,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        public void videoCapture()
        {
            Intent videoCapture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            if(videoCapture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
                startActivityForResult(videoCapture,REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

            }
        }
```

first display video mode than i touch back button than display camera image so i required to swam in video to image mode directly how can possible ?

Comment: you need to be a bit more clear with your question.Does this answer help in any way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748605/starting-video-camera-with-intent?

Comment: You can use two button one for image and another for video and then call the methods on their click listeners.